# Regex - Audit Password Complexity

Tags: regex

My business uses a KeePass database to store credentials.

I want to create a audit of this database to find passwords that do not meet the complexity requirements.

- Longer than 10
- 1 Uppercase
- 1 Lowercase
- 1 Number

Testing the following:

```
^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$

tooshort
TooShort
longerpwd
LongerPwd
L0ngerPwd
l0ngerpwd1
L0ngerpwd1
```

This matches on 'L0ngerpwd1' as it meets the requirements. However, for the audit I want to invert this query to find the rest.

Can someone help me reversing this please?

Comment: Your regex is not correct since `.*` at the start invalidates the length check. You need to fix it as `^(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$` at least, or just `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}$`. As for reversing, why not just use the programming method like `!re.test(str)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the positive lookaheads with negative ones and OR them together:

```
^(?:(?!.{10,})|(?!.*\d)|(?!.*[a-z])|(?!.*[A-Z])).*$
```

As @Wiktor mentioned in his comment, an alternative to this would be to just negate your current positive password regex.  But if you're not using the regex in the context of an app language, this may not be an option.

## Demo